# Есть ли способ получить opera dragonfly локально?

Tags: отладка, opera, javascript, консоль

Дело в том, что я тестирую скрипты оффлайн и для оперы у меня нет дебаггера. Opera dragonfly требует подключения к интернету. Firebug не предлагать. Хочется именно dragonfly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Opera Dragonfly не работает без интернета? Исправляем.](http://rb.labtodo.com/page/use-opera-dragonfly-offline)

> Ситуацию, однако, можно исправить. Для этого надо установить Dragonfly локально, скачав архив с http://dragonfly.opera.com/app/zips/ и указать местоположение файла client-en.xml в настройках Developer Tools.